# Cleanest way to apply a list of boolean functions to a list?

Tags: haskell

Consider this:

```
ruleset = [rule0, rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, rule5]
```

where `rule0`, `rule1`, etc. are boolean functions that take one argument. What is the cleanest way to find if all elements of a particular list satisfy all the rules in the `ruleset`?

Obviously, a loop would work, but Haskell folks always seem to have clever one-liners for these types of problems.

The `all` function seems appropriate (eg. `all (== check_one_element) ruleset`) or nested `map`s. Also, `map ($ anElement) ruleset` is roughly what I want, but for all elements.

I'm a novice at Haskell and the many ways one could approach this problem are overwhelming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you require *all* the functions to be true for *each* argument, then it's just

```
and (ruleset <*> list)
```

(You'll need to `import Control.Applicative` to use `<*>`.)

Explanation:

When `<*>` is given a pair of lists, it applies each function from the list on the left to each argument from the list on the right, and gives back a list containing all the results.

Comment: Thanks, this is clever and definitely the cleanest, but the need to import `Control.Applicative` might be a deal-breaker.

Comment: Really great answer. Just for completeness, could also use `ap` from `Control.Monad` as `and (ruleset \`ap\` list)`.

Comment: @David: If you want to get along without Control.Applicative, use a list comprehension:  `and [ r v | r <- rs, v <- vs ]`.  If this is about shortest code stuff:  `and$rs>>=(\`map\`xs)`

Comment: Thanks all, tremendously appreciated. (I checked and I think importing `Control.Applicative` is actually probably fine for my application)

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

-- sample data
rulesetL = [ (== 1), (>= 2), (<= 3) ]
list = [1..10]

result = and $ concatMap (sequence rulesetL) list
```

(The type we're working on here is `Integer`, but it could be anything else.)

Let me explain what's happening: `rulesetL` is of type `[Integer -> Bool]`. By realizing that `(->) e` is a monad, we can use

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

which in our case will get specialized to type `[Integer -> Bool] -> (Integer -> [Bool])`. So

```
sequence rulesetL :: Integer -> [Bool]
```

will pass a value to all the rules in the list. Next, we use `concatMap` to apply this function to `list` and collect all results into a single list. Finally, calling

```
and :: [Bool] -> Bool
```

will check that all combinations returned `True`.

**Edit:** Check out *dave4420*'s answer, it's nicer and more concise. Mine answer could help if you'd need to combine rules and apply them later on some lists. In particular

```
liftM and . sequence :: [a -> Bool] -> (a -> Bool)
```

combines several rules into one. You can also extend it to other similar combinators like using `or` etc. Realizing that rules are values of `(->) a` monad can give you other useful combinators, such as:

```
andRules = liftM2 (&&) :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
orRules  = liftM2 (||) :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
notRule  = liftM not :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
         -- or just (not .)
```

etc. (don't forget to import `Control.Monad.Reader`).

Answer (score 1):

An easier-to-understand version (without using `Control.Applicative`):

```
satisfyAll elems ruleset = and $ map (\x -> all ($ x) ruleset) elems
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like this way of writing the function, as the only combinator it uses explicitly is `and`:

```
allOkay ruleset items = and [rule item | rule <- ruleset, item <- items]
```